# HTML / CSS | Scrollbar - change color on div and thumb hover

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want my scrollbar of my scrollable div to have a light base color, then change darker when hovering over the scrollable div, then go black when hovering over the scrollbar thumb.

Unfortunately, with my current CSS, the thumb is only changing to the darker color when hovering over the div, but will not go black.  I suspect this is because the thumb is still technically hovering in the scrollable div, so my div:hover is overwriting my thumb hover.

What can I change to make this work as intended?

---

**HTML/CSS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        div#scrollable{
            border: 5px red solid;
            width: 150px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar{
            width: 10px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
            background: white;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
            background: lightgray;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
            background: gray;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="scrollable">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` is more specific than `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover` which is why you are not seeing your expected behavior.

You can fix this by introducing your behavior in a selector that is more specific still: `div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover`.

**Example:**

```css
div#scrollable {
    border: 5px red solid;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: darkgray;
}

/* Not specific enough, will be overridden
   by the rule above. */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: black;
}

/* Fixed. Now specific enough to achieve
   your desired behavior. */
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="scrollable">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Dakota Methvin, it's getting overided. The simplest way to fix that is with `!important`.

```css
div#scrollable {
  border: 5px red solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: white;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: gray;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers as the "correct answer," both work, are perfectly clear, and have helped me learn!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @YangTegap, that's fine. Just wanted to provide another solution since I had it typed out already